# Mapping values from one list to ranges in another in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 large files. One contains ranges:

```
1234 2345 CA
2346 2567 FL
2568 3000 VA
....
```

The second one has values that are not necessarily ordered:

```
2569
1235
2347
...
```

The values in the first file are ordered. The second element in the first row is less than the first value in the second row and so on.

I need to map the values from the second file to the intervals in the first one and grab the state. For example, the result should be:

```
2569 VA
1235 CA
2347 FL
```

I tried the naive approach and parsed all the tuples from the first file in the list of tuples and then one by one, searched which interval each element from the second file belongs to. That turned out to be incredibly slow. Another approach was :

```
with open(file2) as f:
    for line in f:
        mylist.append(line.rstrip())
```

Since there may be duplicates in file 2, I created a set: `myset=set(mylist)`. That decreased the number of searches, but I am sure there is something that is much faster than this approach.

Comment: Because your first file is ordered, why don't you parse all the tuples as you  first tried but use the [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to look up the state

Comment: How did you try searching your list of tuples? A linear search is indeed going to be slow (`O(N*M)` to find the `M` values in the `N` intervals), but a binary search should be faster (`O(log(N)*M)`).

Comment: I ended up using bisect. Thank you!